# angularjs: how to call a function without scope?

Tags: angularjs

Here is my model

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
    <button id="rainBtn" ng-click="makeItRain()">Make it rain !  </button>      
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="lobbyTab" ng-controller="chatController"></div>
```

And here is my myApp.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
makeItRain = function() {
    alert("ok");
}
```

makeItRain is never called:

How to call the makeItRain() function ?

Comment: what happens when you change ng-click to onclick?

Answer (score 3):

Make a Controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("sky", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.makeItRain = function() {
       alert("ok");
    }
}]);
```

Set the controller

```
<button id="rainBtn" ng-controller="sky" ng-click="makeItRain()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a reference from a global function as an angular expression. One possible way to do this without using a controller is to use `$rootScope` and attach the function during the `.run()` phase, although it is not recommended:

```
myApp.run(function($rootScope) {

  $rootScope.makeItRain = function() {
     alert('Raining!');
  };

});
```

Another way is to abandon the idea of attaching an event handler via `ng-click` directive and simply create a directive. This solution assumes that the event handler you are trying to attach will perform dom manipulations.

```
myApp.directive('makeItRain', function() {
  return function(scope, elem, attr) {
    elem.on('click', function() {
      makeItRain();
    });
  };
});
```

and then attach it in the HTML:

```
<button id="rainBtn" make-it-rain>Make it rain !  </button>
```